# simple drupal 6 question, how to move Author and Date info at the bottom of the page

Tags: drupal-6, customization, drupal-themes

I'm trying to modify the content/article display detail and I'm not sure it that's done from the admin or from the xx.tpl.php file...(and if so which one)

I have something like this (in a custom theme done by someone else..I'm just continuing the work):
Text By: XXX
Date published : YYY

Ipsum lorem ..x.x.x.x.x.x.
.x.x.x.x.x.x.xx..x.x.x.x.x

Comments

I want to move the text by and date.. below the text body..

Answer (score 1):

You can move the author and date by modifying your theme's [node.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.tpl.php/6) file. Specifically, you'll want to move the section that prints $submitted to be below the section that prints $content.

If your theme does not contain a node.tpl.php file, you can [override the default](http://drupal.org/node/173880) by copying the default from /modules/node/node.tpl.php. When adding a new template to your theme, you will need to [clear the theme cache](http://drupal.org/node/337176), in order for the new file to be recognized.

Comment: thanks a bunch, I didn't knew from where to find a default template for that, I thought it was the node file, but I wasn't sure. How about if I want different layouts for different content types?

Comment: You can create different layouts for different content types by creating specific node.tpl.php template files for the specific content types, in the format node-[type].tpl.php. See the Core templates and suggestions page for more details: http://drupal.org/node/190815

Comment: When in doubt about which template file to override, use the Theme developer module: https://drupal.org/project/devel_themer

Comment: node.tpl.php contains only <div class="content clear-block">     <?php print $content ?> </div> , and $content has the actual content, so no way to override it at least from here

Comment: In that case, install the Theme Developer module mentioned above and use it to find the correct template file to override.